# Is a Renjin Session reentrant

Tags: java, renjin

A Session is Renjin is not thread safe as described [here](http://docs.renjin.org/en/latest/library/thread-safety.html), but is it reentrant safe ?

The scenario is calling from java engine.eval("...") that has a Java class that calls again the same engine.eval("..") method. Let's assume we've only one engine instance for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

Note that by calling `engine.eval()` on the original ScriptEngine instance, the expression will be evaluated in the global environment and the R function won't be able to see the R call stack that invoked the Java method.

You can also ask Renjin to pass the current `Context` to your Java method when invoked. For example:

```
class MyJavaClass {
   static SEXP estimate(@Current Context context, SEXP function) {
      return context.evaluate(FunctionCall.newCall(function, IntVector.valueOf(42)));
   }
}
```

And then:

```
import(MyJavaClass)
f <- function(x) x*2
MyJavaClass$estimate(f)  # 84
```

Comment: That's really nice, the issue is having R calling 'our engine' that in his query has R code. It's statelss from the context point of view.